# Como retornar uma lista avinda do banco de dados usando o AsyncTask, e depois entregar para a classe que irá manipula-lá?

Tags: java, android, asynctask

Tenho uma inner class que carrega uma lista advinda do banco de dados, porém no retorno do `doInBackground` ele retorna a lista vazia.

Já testei e o `for` está recebendo direitinho, depois popula a lista, mas quando chega lá embaixo simplesmente devolve vazia.

Depois do background executado, preciso que ele entregue para o `onPostExecute` para que eu consiga pegar a lista como resultado, ou seja, lá vai ter um método esperando a lista e repassar para o recycler.

```
public class CarregaLista extends AsyncTask<Void, String, List<DocumentSnapshot>> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Context context;
    public final String TAG = "documento exist";

    public CarregaLista(Context ctx) {

        this.context = ctx;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setMessage("carregando lista...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<DocumentSnapshot> doInBackground(Void... voidss) {


            try {
                mRefFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                mRefFirestore.collection("user")
                        .get()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshots
                                            = new ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot>();

                                    for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : task.getResult()) {

                                        snapshots.add(snapshot);
                                    }

                                    documentSnapshot = snapshots;
                                }
                            }

                        });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("LOG", "><<<<<<<<><<<<<<" + documentSnapshot.size());


        }

        return documentSnapshot;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<DocumentSnapshot> listaRecebida) {

        pegaLista(documentSnapshot);


        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.d("LOG", "><<<<<<<<><<<<<<" + documentSnapshot.size());
    }

}
```

Comment: Troque por `pegaLista(listaRecebida);`

Comment: desculpa não entendi

Comment: ah tá entendi,então já fiz não deu certo também,esse é o problema a lista chega vazia

Comment: Então não sei, vou ficar devendo. Era bom postar o código completo como sugeriu o autor da resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você não mostrou a declaração de `documentSnapshots`. Faça ela assim:

```
private final List<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshots =
    new ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot>();
```

Depois, na linha em que você popula `snapshots`, popule `documentSnapshots`:

```
documentSnapshots.add(snapshot);
```

Comment: bom dia marcelo eu fiz a declaração na classe externa,eu declaro ela dessa forma que você passou aonde ? dentro da inner class ?

Comment: Onde estiver declarado hoje, troque pela sugestão.